# Nexus Maven proxy change address and I got Error in SCALA builds

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, nexus

I use Nexus for Proxy Scala Repository but have this Error!
My Nexus Maven2 Proxy configuration is:
[image]

For example I want to get `https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.github.gseitz/sbt-release/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.0/jars/sbt-release.jar`

But Nexus try to download from below address:
`https://x.x.x.x/repository/sbt-plugin-releases/com/github/gseitz/sbt-release_2.10_0.13/1.0.0/sbt-release-1.0.0.pom`

change this part of address **.../com.github.gseitz/...** to **.../com/github/gseitz/...**

Comment: Is that Nexus that tries to download from the second URL? Or is that your laptop that uses this Nexus URL?

Comment: SBT plugins do not have same repository structure as maven dependencies. You have to tweak some things. Have a look to https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/SBT+Repositories for instance (not for Nexus but idea is the same).

Comment: @GaëlJ my laptop use nexus URL, When I Upload manually Jars to nexus It works!

Comment: Then you likely have to configure your SBT settings properly so that it uses right pattern when trying to download from Nexus.